# How to get polychrom's cordova-android-actionbar to show menu

Tags: cordova, plugins, android-actionbar, phonegap-plugins

I'm having trouble getting the Android navigation menu to show in the actionbar. Is it supposed to be there by default with this plugin?

I did get the actionbar to show with:

```
@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar
preference name="fullscreen" value="false"
preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"
```

but I don't think the plugin is running after installing both the old way and the new plugin way with the cordova plugin add' command on a new project. I've tried so many different things like referencing the javascript file in various locations and trying to implement the old method that constantly left me with an error at 
`Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR`. I still cannot get the Android navigation menu in the actionbar to show up even with this new plugin method. Anyone get this working as it seems like a worthwhile way to get a cordova app to look and feel more native.

reference:
[cordova-android-actionbar](https://github.com/polychrom/cordova-android-actionbar)